# Fetching a file filepath on a live website in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-deployment

We are designing a website using .NET

The website has a folders containing some files. User enters the name of the file and we have to fetch data from that file. On our pc in Visual Studio, we were using StreamReader like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\UserName\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\teach\\uploads\\Submission\\" + filename;
```

**But now, we are going live with our website and the problem is the file path? What should we give exactly? The files are in /compiler/Submission folder.**

Comment: You may want to keep your files somewhere other than your web folder - a shared network drive, or a hosted solution like AWS or Azure might be better, for lots of different reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath`

It could be something like this

```
var yourPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads")
```

Where `~` is replaced by .NET for the root of your virtual directory.

Comment: thnks, i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

> you can't access files directly using drive location.

try
 assume your live website at `www.mydomian.com` and you can view the file 
as

```
www.mydomian.com\uploads\myfile.txt
```

then use:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"www.mydomian.com\uploads\" + filename);
```

or [Daniel A. White's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29523407/2607840)

```
var yourPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"+filename)
```

Comment: thnks, i will try it out